# Search in Jaeger ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, jaeger

My query from the Jaeger ElasticSearc returns the following entry

```
    "_index" : "jaeger-span-2020-07-31",
    "_type" : "span",
    "_source" : {
      "startTime" : 1596157225275112,
      "startTimeMillis" : 1596157225275,
      "duration" : 0,
      "tags" : [
        {
          "key" : "span.kind",
          "type" : "string",
          "value" : "server"
        },
        {
          "key" : "internal.span.format",
          "type" : "string",
          "value" : "zipkin"
        }
      ],
      "process" : {
        "serviceName" : "transaction-manager",
      }
    }
  }
```

My goal is to find entries which have tag["internal.span"] "zipkin". Field "tags" is "nested". I am trying a query like the one below. I do not get hits. What do I miss?

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "query": { 
          "bool": {
              "must": [ 
                  {"match": { "process.serviceName": "transaction-manager" }},
                  {
                          "nested": {
                              "path": "tags",
                              "query": {
                                  "match": {
                                      "value": "zipkin"
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make use of `tags.value` instead of `value` in your match query.

Below query should help:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "process.serviceName": "transaction-manager"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "tags.value": "zipkin"        <---- Note this
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```